# Why is there no compiler warning for comparing DateTime to null?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, compiler-warnings

Visual Studio shows compiler warning [CS04721](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0472) under `(int)5 == null` which reads

> The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type
> 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'

```
bool x = (int)5 == null;
```

However, there is no warning if a `DateTime` object is used.

```
bool y = DateTime.UtcNow == null;
```

Since `DateTime` is not `Nullable<DateTime>`, it can never be null. What's the reason a similar warning is not shown for the second statement?

Comment: Not an expert on the language, but you can use the "?" symbol after the object type that makes an object nullable. If you can save a reference to the date/time object this way, then the comparison makes sense.

Comment: If you think there should be a message, you can always propose to Microsoft that they add one.

Comment: I get a compiler warning https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOjSX.png

Comment: I get a warning with this code as well. Can you post an [mre] that *doesn't* ?

Comment: @gunr2171 I don't get that. Are you using ReSharper or anything like that? Btw I've enabled .NET 7.

Comment: It might depend on the editor, as [dotnet fiddle using .Net 7](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wzdSXU) doesn't show the warning. My screenshot is from VS 2022 (17.4.1) .Net 7.

Comment: I've reproduced the issue in VS 17.4.0.

Comment: Re nothing to contribute: I just dislike questions that ask us to guess what Microsoft were thinking when they implemented something, or why they didn't implement something. With the exceptions of the rare occasions when someone from Microsoft answers with in-the-room knowledge, such questions generally ask for opinions and opinion-based answers are off-topic here. "Why isn't it working for me with this IDE version, this C# version, and this .NET version?" would have an objective answer and therefore be on-topic, but "why did Microsoft do this like this?" isn't really.

Comment: I wasn't looking for a guess. My intention was to find out if there was a real syntax-related reason a warning like this would not be thrown as in "Is there something specific about DateTime that requires a different treatment?". Read the question again. I did NOT ask about "Microsoft" anywhere in my question. Your interpretation is way off.

Comment: @user246392 C# is a language developed by Microsoft. .net is a frameork/library whatever developed and maintained by Microsoft. Visual Studio is a Microsoft product. The compiler used by Visual Studio is a Microsoft compiler. The documentation you linked is from a Microsoft page. So ... yes you did ask about Microsoft.

Comment: @gunr2171: dotnet fiddle also doesn't show the warning with target Framework 4.7.2, which is kinda bizarre.

Comment: I'll accept that my understanding of what your question is about might not be what you intended, but multiple people have upvoted my comment suggesting that perhaps they also interpreted it the same way as I did. Given your comment now, I guess it's more narrowly defined to "why isn't this working for me?" rather than "why isn't this part of C#/.NET/IntelliSense?" so I'll accept that.

Comment: "multiple people have upvoted my comment" doesn't mean much when you can't downvote comments.

Comment: To me this answer is useless (again, to me, other people might find it helpful). As shown the answer is "because it wasn't yet implemented". Very uninteresting.

Comment: @rshepp I don't really understand the relevance of your comment. I didn't say that the general consensus is that it's off-topic, I said that presumably those people also interpreted it the same way as I did. I'm afraid that downvotes still don't take away personal experiences and an individual's own interpretation of something. Think of an election: not everybody votes for the same candidate, but there's only one winner. You can't just pretend like it was a unanimous vote for the winner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code

```
bool x = (int)5 == null;
```

produces the warning number `CS0472` which has existed since the first version of C#.

The code

```
bool y = DateTime.UtcNow == null;
```

produces the warning number `CS8073`. According to [its help page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/warning-waves), the warning `CS8073` is part of the "warning wave 5" and was only introduced with C# version 9.

So you will see the warning when using C# 9 or newer and you won't see it when using older versions.

Whether you see the warning will also be influenced by the " AnalysisLevel" you configure in the project options of your project. To see warning `CS8073`, you should have enabled warning level 5 or higher.

Warning `CS8073` specifically applies to struct types while the older warning deals with built-in primitive value types.

---

There is a [blog post by Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/automatically-find-latent-bugs-in-your-code-with-net-5/) that announces the introduction of new warnings. According to the blog post, warning `CS8073` was introduced because it deals with a "common coding mistake".

---

Why the warning hasn't been implemented earlier can only be guessed. My guess is the following:

The comparison operator from the first example with the type `int` is built into the language, while the equality operator in the second example is an operator overload in the class `DateTime` that is implemented as C# code in [the .net Framework source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,df6b1eba7461813b).

So, in order to generate the warning in the second case, the Compiler has to look at the actual implementation of the struct type and its available operator overloads.

There could in fact be an overload that allows using the equality operator with a struct type and a different reference type in which case the warning would not be justified because the comparison with `null` could return `true`.

Example of a program where the comparison of a `struct type` with `null` will return `true` (Nullable option is disabled):

```
internal class Program
{
    public struct X
    {
        public static bool operator ==(X s1, object s2) => s1.Equals(s2);
        public static bool operator !=(X s1, object s2) => s1.Equals(s2);
        public override bool Equals(object other) => true;
        public override int GetHashCode() => 0;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        X x = new X();
        bool b = x == null;
        Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
}
```